# LSTM for concaneted layers

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to process 5 layers through LSTM but facing an error.
Below is the code.

```
yhdistelma=layers.concatenate([input1,input2, 
                              input3, input4, 
                              input5, input6, 
                              input7, input8, input9])

first_output  = layers.Dense(30,name='output_1')(yhdistelma)
second_output = layers.Dense(30,name='output_2')(yhdistelma)
third_output  = layers.Dense(30,name='output_3')(yhdistelma)
fourth_output = layers.Dense(30,name='output_4')(yhdistelma)
fifth_output  = layers.Dense(30,name='output_5')(yhdistelma)

hhs= layers.concatenate([first_output, second_output, 
                         third_output, fourth_output, 
                         fifth_output])

xxs=layers.LSTM(5)(hhs)
```

The error gave while `model.compile` is

```
 Input 0 of layer lstm_2 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 150)
```

Answer (score 0):

The input shape of `LSTM` supposed to be a 3D tensor such as `[batch, timesteps, feature]`. For your case, you can expand the input dimension of it as follows:

```
from tensorflow.keras import layers

yhdistelma    = layers.Input(20)
first_output  = layers.Dense(30, name='output_1')(yhdistelma)
second_output = layers.Dense(30, name='output_2')(yhdistelma)
third_output  = layers.Dense(30, name='output_3')(yhdistelma)
fourth_output = layers.Dense(30, name='output_4')(yhdistelma)
fifth_output  = layers.Dense(30, name='output_5')(yhdistelma)
hhs = layers.concatenate([first_output, second_output, 
                         third_output, fourth_output, 
                         fifth_output])
xxs = layers.LSTM(5)(tf.expand_dims(hhs, axis=-1))


print(hhs.shape)
print(tf.expand_dims(hhs, axis=-1).shape)
print(xxs.shape)
(None, 150)
(None, 150, 1)
(None, 5)
```

Comment: Can we make it (None, 5, 30) instead of (None, 150, 1)?

Comment: I think you misunderstood. The shape of `None, 150, 1` is coming from `hhs` and `(None, 5`)` is coming from `LSTM`.  That's two output are different context.